# I wanted to download ffmpeg on a Mac High Sierra version 10.13.6, but something happend

Tags: mac, ffmpeg, macos-highsierra

==> You are using macOS 10.13.

==> We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
This installation may not succeed.
After installation, you will encounter build failures with some formulae.
Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on Homebrew's GitHub,
Twitter or IRC. You are responsible for resolving any issues you experience
while you are running this old version.

==> This script will install:
/usr/local/bin/brew
/usr/local/share/doc/homebrew
/usr/local/share/man/man1/brew.1
/usr/local/share/zsh/site-functions/_brew
/usr/local/etc/bash_completion.d/brew
/usr/local/Homebrew

Press RETURN to continue or any other key to abort

==> /usr/bin/sudo /usr/sbin/chown -R Vilmos:admin /usr/local/Homebrew

==> Downloading and installing Homebrew...
remote: Enumerating objects: 6, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (6/6), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Total 6 (delta 3), reused 5 (delta 3), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (6/6), done.
From https://github.com/Homebrew/brew

196ec61a3..aa14e48f4  master     -> origin/master
Checking out files: 100% (2775/2775), done.
HEAD is now at aa14e48f4 Merge pull request #11605 from dawidd6/simulate-force-linux-prefix
fatal: Needed a single revision
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).

==> Installation successful!

==> Homebrew has enabled anonymous aggregate formulae and cask analytics.
Read the analytics documentation (and how to opt-out) here:
https://docs.brew.sh/Analytics
No analytics data has been sent yet (or will be during this `install` run).

==> Homebrew is run entirely by unpaid volunteers. Please consider donating:
https://github.com/Homebrew/brew#donations

==> Next steps:

- Run `brew help` to get started
- Further documentation:
  https://docs.brew.sh
  brew install ffmpeg
  Updating Homebrew...
  fatal: Needed a single revision

==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
Error: No available formula or cask with the name "ffmpeg".

==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.

==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.

Comment: In the Mac world, you must stay on top of software updates or the market leaves you behind like this. Update to macOS Big Sur 11.4 (current as of this writing) and try again. If macOS High Sierra 10.13.x is the latest your Mac supports, then your Mac is a decade old and you are engaging in a retrocomputing hobby.

Comment: which file do I put it in?

Comment: I didn't say anything about putting anything in any file. I linked you to a duplicate question someone asked a couple weeks ago, which someone else had already answered.